# Tuxedo Client 12 Crash

Tags: oracle, crash, tuxedo

We are observing frequent crashes of our Production JVM which runs webMethods v9.12.

After analyzing the crash dumps, we came to conclusion that the reason could be some of the libraries in Tuxedo 12.1.1.0 Client because the crash dump mentioned that the problematic frame was in libwsc.so.71.

To give a history of the issue, the problem of Crash was existing from long time when we were running older version of webMethods (8.2) on JVM 1.6. When we were installing the same, we observed these frequent crashes with Tuxedo 8.x. So, up on advice from our Tuxedo Server Ops Team, we upgraded the Tuxedo client to 12.1.1.0 which reduced the number of crashes considerably.

However, now after upgrading to version 9.12, we are observing the issue of frequent crashes again.

### Before Upgrade:

Java Version: 1.6.0_27
Tuxedo: 12.1.1.0

### After Upgrade:

Java Version: 1.8.0_151
Tuxedo: 12.1.1.0

Please find sample crash file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cit7mbG0vbqK-X3r0RU6S4aUxyLIhRCk/view?usp=sharing)

Appreciate any pointers to resolve these crash issues.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to report this issue on https://support.oracle.com/ and try to get some help there. I've reported several Tuxedo issues there myself and got fixes or workarounds.

I think StackOverflow is a bad place for asking such questions about Oracle's proprietary software. Programming, configuration - yes, crashes - no/